# What to do about questions that sound like malware?

Tags: discussion

I have come across a handful of questions in my time here where it seems as though the author's are attempting to build functionality that could/will be used as part of malware.

What action should we take in these cases?

Downvoting seems insufficient given the potential severity, however, flagging seems heavy handed, especially considering the planned usage could be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that no action should be taken. Vote and flag based on the quality and usefulness of the post. It's very difficult to assess if someone actually has malicious intent, or if they are "white-hat hacking."

Comment: _Assume good faith_. You're not. Maybe you shouldn't start from the assumption that something that could be used in malware will be.

Comment: Every one of those kind of posts says clearly 'for education', 'white hat' or some such.  I don't believe any of them.  many are of such low standard that it's competely clear that they ar eno white-hat investigator, but kiddies who wnat SO to teach them how to write malware.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit You've read what the others posted and what the dupe says: Be as naive as you can until OP says "I wants hack somebudy".

Comment: @Tom IANAL, but I strongly suspect that a prosecution lawyer, Judge and/or jury would fall over laughing at that defense when you stand in the dock, a co-conspirator in some computer fraud case.  Say goodbye to your house, hello to gen. pop. :)

Comment: It's a sorta general 'given' that a person skilled and experienced in some field is expected to be duly diligent in their activities in that field.  As a software developer, you would be crucified in court if you stated that you aided a malware developer because you were 'being nice'.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit You're neither a lawyer, nor do you recognize irony ;P.

Comment: On your own head be it...